# C# DataColumn convert byte[] to string with expression

Tags: c#, sql-server, byte, datacolumn

I make SQL queries that must be retrieved in a datable (it is a constraint of the data provider)
My goal is to limit the processing loops on the data table (possibility to have several millions of rows)
I have a Gupta SQLBASE 11.6 database and its .net data provider
I use the code below to retrieve the contents of the database and manipulate it.
LONGVARCHAR columns (equivalent to Varchar (Max) of sql server) are received as a byte []

I added a column in the table and defined an expression.

```
tempcol.Expression = System.String.Format("Convert({0}, System.String)", ds.Tables[0].Columns[CurrentColumn].ColumnName);
```

Unfortunately this returns the type of the column as a string ("System.Byte []")

Do you have an idea to convert this type of columns into text form without making a loop?

```
public void MakeSQLBaseConnection(string StringQuery) {
    SQLBaseConnection sqconn = new SQLBaseConnection(constr);
    string err = "Log is saved to C:\\OurErrorlog2.txt. \r\n\r\nSQLBase .NET Provider Error: \r\nConnection String: " + constr + "\r\n";
    try {
        sqconn.Open();
        SQLBaseDataAdapter sqad = new SQLBaseDataAdapter(StringQuery, sqconn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sqad.Fill(ds);
        for (int CurrentColumn = 0; CurrentColumn < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; CurrentColumn++) {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Columns[CurrentColumn].DataType == typeof(char[]) || ds.Tables[0].Columns[CurrentColumn].DataType == typeof(byte[])) {
                DataColumn tempcol = new DataColumn();
                tempcol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
                tempcol.Caption = ds.Tables[0].Columns[CurrentColumn].Caption;
                tempcol.ColumnName = ds.Tables[0].Columns[CurrentColumn].ColumnName;
                ds.Tables[0].Columns[CurrentColumn].Caption = System.String.Concat(ds.Tables[0].Columns[CurrentColumn].Caption, "_hidden");
                ds.Tables[0].Columns[CurrentColumn].ColumnName = ds.Tables[0].Columns[CurrentColumn].Caption;
                ds.Tables[0].Columns[CurrentColumn].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
                tempcol.Expression = System.String.Format("Convert({0}, System.String)", ds.Tables[0].Columns[CurrentColumn].ColumnName);
                ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(tempcol);
                tempcol.SetOrdinal(ds.Tables[0].Columns[CurrentColumn].Ordinal);
                CurrentColumn++;
            }
        }   
        dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        sqconn.Close();
    } catch (SQLBaseException myException) {
        err += "Message: " + myException.Message + "\r\n";
        err += "StackTrace: \r\n" + myException.StackTrace.ToString();

        MessageBox.Show(err);
        StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(".\\OurErrorlog2.txt", true);
        s.Write(err);
        s.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the data really text?  Without know the format of the binary data I can't answer the question.

Comment: Yes : Only text

Comment: LongVar is 64 bits so it is packed.  So use Convert.FromBase64String()  which return a byte[].  The you need to use Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte[])

Comment: Sorry. it doesn't work . datacolumn.expression only support Convert().
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx

Do you have another idea?

Comment: I thought you were getting  LONGVARCHAR and missed you were actually getting byte[].  To get string from byte[] : string base64String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte[]);  Then use string = Convert.FromBase64String(string)